# How to count the amount of dates on field?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to count the number of dates as example, I would like my results are: 14.

Im my example results, ***I'am showing a select with distinct,*** I have same date repeated several times, however count quantity the lines dont solv my problem.

How do I select this in SQL Server?

```
fk_date
2016-08-01
2016-08-02
2016-08-03
2016-08-04
2016-08-05
2016-08-08
2016-08-09
2016-08-10
2016-08-11
2016-08-12
2016-08-15
2016-08-16
2016-08-17
2016-08-18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `COUNT(DISTINCT)` for this:

```
SELECT 
   COUNT (DISTINCT fk_date)
FROM 
   table
```

As described in the reference for [COUNT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx):

> DISTINCT
>   Specifies that COUNT returns the number of unique nonnull values.